# finding Injective and Surjective function between two sets

Tags: functions

I wanted to know if there are any important guidelines which can help one understand better the concept of finding an Injective and Surjective function between two sets.
For example: from N to Z --> 
[image]

When the first line is when n is even and the second line is when n is odd.
I was told this is mostly intuitive.
Is it? Is there a method for finding a function like that? split/not split (depends on the sets of course...)

Answer (score 1):

In general there is no real method of finding such functions. Especially when the sets are getting more complex it can get really difficult.

In your case the solution is indeed intuitive.

The difference of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is that $\mathbb{Z}$ has negative elements. 
So in some sense, there are two types of elements (besides $0$). Some which are positive and negative ones.

In $\mathbb{N}$ you also have two different types of elements. Namely odd ones and even elements. 
So it makes sense to connect these.

And this is something you can look for.

Also it could come in handy to know other concepts by heart like "back-and-forth", or of course Cantor's diagonal argument.

Unfortunatly I can not give/link examples at the moment, but I might do later.